# Spring Data Elastic Search: How to ignore mapping of hashset field

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, mapping, jhipster, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have two documents **User** & **Activity**, Both of them are indexed and I want to search user by firstName and lastName

User

```java
@org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document(indexName = "user")
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Text, fielddata = true)
    private String firstName;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Text, fielddata = true)
    private String lastName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    @Field(type = FieldType.Nested)
    private Set<Activity> activities = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Activity

```java
@org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document(indexName = "activity")
@Entity
public class Activity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Text, fielddata = true)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private User user;
}
```

but I'm always getting this exception as follows

> Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) failed to map source through reference user["Activity"]->java.util.HashSet[0]

I'm using generated app with Jhipster 6.7.0 with Spring Data Elastic 3.2.7 and ES6.8.6 
I'm really stuck for two weeks, I need to do my search without annotating "**activities**" field with **@JsonIgnore**
I have many documents in my project that provide HashSet fields and I'm new to elastic so any optimized approach about how to ignore or map this kind of fields is very helpful.

Comment: There never was a 3.3 version of Spring Data Elasticsearch. After 3.2 came 4.0

Comment: On which operation and entity do you get this error?

Comment: sorry @P.J.Meisch i have edited the question i m using spring data elasticsearch 3.2.7 and quering the user entity like that `BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().should(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("*"+query+"*").field("firstName").field("lastName").lenient(true);`

Comment: Does the user document stored in Elasticsearch contain activities? Elasticsearch can not join different document types from different indices like a relational database

Comment: yes , user document contain activities list and only the id activity is mapped .

Comment: can you please add the index mappings from Elasticsearch for the user index and what Elasticsearch returns for a document _/user/_doc/{userId}_ for some given `userId`?

Comment: I can't produce the error. Can you add error full stack trace and an example user & activity save and query details?

Comment: @İsmailDurmaz   http://txt.do/185ck

Comment: @barsawi13 can you share `com.demo.app.config.ElasticsearchConfiguration` content? I have a clue but I want to be sure

Comment: @İsmailDurmaz https://textuploader.com/18d16

Comment: @barsawi13 I created a sample project and posted the document, but I can't get any error. Maybe you share your project on the GitHub (it can be only related classes), I should execute your codes

Comment: Sorry it s confidential i can't share the whole project

Comment: I have tried many ways, however, I can't catch any error. Every time, it works successfully. I think the problem is related to `ObjectMapper`. Create new in `CustomEntityMapper` constructor method that there are no arguments instead of `CustomEntityMapper(ObjectMapper objectMapper)`. Create new`ObjectMapper` instance and use it. Change deserialize configurations for this instance.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
```

at the top of  you pojo. Like this:

```
    @org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document(indexName = "activity")
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Activity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Text, fielddata = true)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private User user;
}
```

> Edit:
> The @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) would be over User pojo. Because you want to ignore Activity instantiation in the User Pojo. Also do not instantiate the Set as new HashSet. Hope this helps!

Comment: still getting same exception